# Java Generics: Unchecked cast in generic List even though already checked with instanceof

Tags: java, android, generics

So I have a method which gets an ArrayList  (Parameter) and it should return the same Type of ArrayList:

```
   static ArrayList<?> readFromFileToArrayList (Activity activity, String name, ArrayList<?> data) {

    try {
        String savedData = FileReadWrite.readFromFile(activity, name);

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(savedData);
        if(data.get(0) instanceof String){
            ArrayList<String> specificData= (ArrayList<String>) data;
            for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                if(!data.contains(jsonArray.optString(i))){
                    specificData.add(jsonArray.optString(i));
                }
            }
            return specificData;
        }
```

For this implementation I get an "Unchecked Cast warning". Of course I can use "SuppressWarnings" but I am looking for a better solution or is this solution with "SuppressedWarnings" already considered as a clean solution?

Thanks for everything and yes I have already searched Stackoverflow for an answer. But I don't really know if this is still hacky or clean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reuse `data`, in fact it's poor design to have side effects like that. The method returns a list; it should not mutate one of its parameters.

Simply create a *new* list and populate it with `data`:

```
ArrayList<String> specificData = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object obj : data)
    specificData.add(obj.toString());
```

You can keep the rest of your code the same. You will now not have any warnings (or side-effects!).

Comment: Since I dont really know that much about Java 8, I have some follow-up questions:
1. Thats only possible if I have data like String, int .. in the Arraylist and not with List of self-built Datatpyes right?
2. Somehow "data.stream()" doesn't work on Android studio. (Already included "import java.util.stream.*;" and configured gradle) Is there something I am missing? 


Thanks for your reply.


PS Can't vote your answer up since I dont have enough reputation. Please upvote my question so that I can upvote yours ;)

Comment: @Ayox you didn't tag your question with [tag:android] (I added it for you). Android doesn't support java 8. I have modified my answer to use java 7, which is compatible with android.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything :)
As far as I know, they do with Android N.
[link](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html)

Answer (score 3):

In general, just because `data.get(0)` is a `String` doesn't mean that all of the other elements are, so the compiler can't know that it's safe.

(And, actually, it's still always an unsafe cast, even after an `instanceof` check).

In this case, it is reasonable to add `@SuppressWarnings` to the declaration of `specificData`, because of what you know about the JSON library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

PS Can't vote your answer up since I dont have enough reputation. Please upvote my question so that I can upvote yours ;)